# как реализовать корзину без входа в аккаунт

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, yii2

ситуация такая, хочу сделать так чтобы человек  без входа в аккаунт мог добавлять товары в свою корзину, а если он захочет войти в свой акк то добавленные в корзине были видны именно у него, какая логика там должна быть?

Comment: Добрый день. Cookies, токен...

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете реализовывать это с помощью cookie или local storage. Например пользователь зашел на сайт присвоить ему уникальный индентификатор, можно сгенерировать хеш, или что-то другое на Ваш выбор. Дальше сохраняете этот индентификатор в cookie или в local storage. Когда пользователь начинает выбирать товары, если корзина реализована через БД, то можно создавать в таблице корзины поле для индентификатора и записывать туда этот интдентификатор и когда пользователь регистрируется или логуеться проверять его уникальный индентификатор существует ли он в таблице корзин, если да то присвоить ее этому пользователю.